# save fields values during form submit

Tags: php

I want that when the user submits the form, and some reason happen some error, I want that the fields that the user already wrote to be saved, so I want to be show the values the user already wrote.

Im doing this with code below, but I dont understand why, when I submit the form the fields stay empty.

Somebody there see something wrong?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sendForm'])) {
    $f['name']    = $_POST['name'];
    $f['content'] = $_POST['content'];
    $f['date']    = $_POST['date'];
} ?>

<form name="form" action="" method="post">

    <label class="line">
        <span class="data">Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($f['name'])) echo $f['name']; ?>"/>
    </label>

    <label class="line">
        <span class="data">Content:</span>
        <textarea name="content" rows="3" value="<?php if (isset($f['content'])) echo $f['content']; ?>"></textarea>
    </label>

    <label class="line">
        <span class="data">Date:</span>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php if (isset($f['date'])) {
            echo $f['date'];
        } else {
            echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        } ?>"/>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" name="sendForm" class="btn"/>

</form>
```

Comment: close the php as `?>` before the form code

Comment: Thanks but that is not  the problem, because before this I have a else inside a php, and this question code is inside that else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can set by this way,

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />
```

You do not need to use `$f['name']`. you can get value directly by `$_POST['name']` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but Im also using this fields for a insert statment like: $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (name,content, , date) VALUES (:name, :content, :date)");  
     $insert->bindValue(':name', $f['name']);
     $insert->bindValue(':content', $f['content']);
     $insert->bindValue(':date', $f['date']);
    
     $insert->execute();

Comment: you can use PDO thats good but with in page scope you can use $_POST variable for saving last field value.